# Как исправить код, чтобы фигуры и их названия перемещались даже с одинаковыми названиями?

Tags: vba, макросы

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить код, если это возможно.

---

Есть рабочий макрос, который используется для составления планограмм, перемещения фигур и вывода названия фигур в список.
Но проблема в том, что если фигуры имеют одинаковые название, то макрос перемещает первую. Приходится к названию фигуры добавлять дополнительные знаки (`.-=+-` и т.п.).
Возможно ли исправить код, чтобы даже с одинаковыми названиями перемещались фигуры и их названия?

```
Public Object1 As String
Public Object2 As String
Public iNumber As Integer

Sub Obj1ToObj2(Obj1, Obj2, Optional Steps = 20)
  Const dt# = 0.02
  Dim x1#, x2#, y1#, y2#, x#, y#, t!
  Dim l1#, t1#, w1#, h1#, l2#, t2#, w2#, h2#
  With Obj1
    l1 = .Left: t1 = .Top: w1 = .Width: h1 = .Height
  End With
  With Obj2
    l2 = .Left: t2 = .Top: w2 = .Width: h2 = .Height
  End With
  x1 = l1 + w1 / 2
  y1 = t1 + h1 / 2
  x2 = l2 + w2 / 2
  y2 = t2 + h2 / 2
  With Obj1
    For x = x1 To x2 Step (x2 - x1) / Steps
      y = (x2 * y1 - x1 * y2 - (y1 - y2) * x) / (x2 - x1)
      .Left = x - w1 / 2
      .Top = y - h1 / 2
      t = Timer + dt
      While Timer < t:  Wend
      DoEvents:
    Next
    x = x2: y = y2: .Left = x - w1 / 2: .Top = y - h1 / 2
    DoEvents
  End With
End Sub

Sub GotoCell()
Dim Rng As Range, RngShape As Range
Object1 = Application.Caller
Set RngShape = Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Object1).TopLeftCell.Address)
    If Not Intersect(RngShape, Range("C5:AF16")) Is Nothing Then
        Set Rng = Columns(1).Find(what:=RngShape.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Rng.Offset(0, 1) = ""
        End If
    End If
    With Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
        Obj1ToObj2 .Shapes(Object1), .Range(Object2)
    End With
    Set Rng = Columns(1).Find(what:=iNumber, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Rng.Offset(0, 1) = Application.Caller
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Когда пишете код, думайте о том, что он не только для Вас. Переменным нужно давать осмысленные названия. Читать его не то, чтобы трудно, но - затруднительно. Возможно, при хороших переменных и помощь получили бы быстрее.

Comment: Чтобы различать фигуры c одинаковыми `.Name`, можно воспользоваться, например, свойствами `.ID` или `.AlternativeText`